# R Shiny: widen d3Tree for long labels

Tags: r, d3.js, shiny, d3tree

Using [d3Tree](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/d3Tree/d3Tree.pdf) R package to visualize a tree in R Shiny with long labels - is it possible to increase the space between nodes of different levels?  Setting the width property doesn't seem to do anything - below is a reproducible example with width set to 1000 (also tried "200%", "auto").

```
library(d3Tree)
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(Titanic) %>% 
  mutate(Sex = paste(Sex, " long name test"), 
         Age = paste(Age, " long name test"))
d3tree(
  data = list(root = df2tree(struct = df,rootname = 'Titanic'), 
  layout = 'collapse'), 
  width = 1000)
```

[image]